# nodejs, how to check if session is defined on every page

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am using express to develop a simple website.
I just get confused about how to make the nodejs check session before rendering any page, so that if a user did not login, he cannot see anything.

I think in rails it is quite simple, just add some codes in the application controller. But how to handle such thing in nodejs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a middleware function to check for authentication before your routes and then call it on each of your routes. For example in your app.js

```
// Define authentication middleware BEFORE your routes
var authenticate = function (req, res, next) {
  // your validation code goes here. 
  var isAuthenticated = true;
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    next();
  }
  else {
    // redirect user to authentication page or throw error or whatever
  }
}
```

Then call this pass this method in your routes (notice the authenticate parameter):

```
app.get('/someUrl', authenticate, function(req, res, next) {
    // Your normal request code goes here
});

app.get('/anotherUrl', authenticate, function(req, res, next) {
    // Your normal request code goes here
});
```

Comment: Yep -- this is the way to handle it.  My only criticism is that as written, you're leaking `authenticate` into global scope.  Use `var` or just write `function authenticate(req, res, next) { ...` instead to keep it scoped to the module.

Comment: But, how should I protect static things? Like if my main page is rewritten as index.html

Comment: @YitongZhou: If you want to run your function for *every* request, just give it to `app.use` rather than in a route handler.  (Of course, now you have to deal with making sure your function skips its checks for the login page and its dependent resources, which can get tricky.)

Comment: is there any other way to check every request in one place instead of adding `authenticate` on every request ?